# Postfix - how to block emails sending out to a particular domain

Tags: postfix, domain, email-server

I am having Postfix installed mailserver and I am using that server for legitimate purpose only.

I need to block some outgoing emails for a particular blacklisted domain. Is there anyway to do through the configurations ?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A closer look at the [**basic access controls**](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists) available should help you out; just specify the appropriate access map in [**smtpd_recipient_restrictions**](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) that denies access to those domains:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/blacklisted_domains, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit
```

and in `/etc/postfix/blacklisted_domains`:

```
bad.domain1    REJECT
bad.domain2    REJECT
baduser@bad.domain3    REJECT
```

Don't forget to `postmap` that file.

Comment: This does not work for TLDs (example: .biz, .info)

Comment: This works from Thunderbird, I blocked some email addresses and I get an error. However, when sending from PHP, the emails go through. How do we also block the PHP `mail()` (mine is setup to use SMTP).